# Why is CSS child element larger than parent (sortables)?

Tags: css, hover, css-position, parent

I have a UL with several LI's.
In these li's there are tables (1 in every li).

I use mootools to make my li's draggable / sortable.
I'll leave the JavaScript out of here though, since it's not part of the problem.

All is well, except I don't want my entire li (and thus child table) to be draggable. Just a small portion so to speak.

I then tried to 'relative and absolute' my way out of this one, but the 'hover' effect of the li remains... So when I hover my (child) table, the (parent) li always shows its: hover effect. Which it shouldn't!

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td><a href="foobar.html">foobar</a></td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </li>
</ul>

<style>
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
  }
  
  li {
    background-color: red;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
  }
  
  li:hover {
    background-color: green;
    cursor: move;
  }
  
  li table {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 850px;
    position: absolute;
  }
</style>
```

If you apply this, you'll see that the actual li is 25x25. But when you hover the table, the li turns green (just that 25x25 part)...

Only that 25x25 part should respond to the hover!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your markup.
You have the table within (sibling of) the List item (li) therefore whatever effect/styling you apply to the li will apply to all that within it; hence why when you hover over the table the li is turning green.

Comment: yeah I know. However, it's unclear to me why I can alter the paren't dimensions, but not its hover-dimensions (so to speak)... It seems a strange thing

Answer (score 0):

When you hover over the `table`, which is a child of `li`, you trigger the `:hover` pseudo-class also for the `li`.

A solution could be to **apply a class to all the li with a table inside**:

```
<li class="withTable">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td><a href="foobar.html">foobar</a></td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</li>
```

**and add this rule to your CSS**:

```
li.withTable:hover {
        background-color:transparent;
        cursor:default;
}
```

Obviously you can set another color if you want

```
li.withTable:hover {
        background-color:blue;
        cursor:default;
}
```

Comment: I just tried what you suggested, but the 25x25 parent-li still turns green when hovering the child-table.

Why would things behave differently when I call the li by class instead of by type?

I'm beginning to fear that what I want isn't possible ;).

Comment: Try setting `li.withTable:hover {background-color:red;}` like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zHNA9/)

Comment: Things behave differently because of [specificity](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-understanding-css-specificity/)

Comment: Hi Elisa, yeah I thought as much. Your fiddle never turns the li green. Not even when the li itself is hovered.

I'm afraid I'll have to alter the javascript of the sortables to solve my problem.